# Unmarshal JSON to minimum type

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have a Json string that I want to unmarshal.
This is working:

```
jsonString := []byte(`{"my_int": 3, "my_string": null}`)
var data map[string]interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(jsonString, &data)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
//avroJson := make(map[string]interface{})
for k, v := range data {
    fmt.Printf("%v, %T\n", k, v)
}
```

My issue is: the value of `my_int` which is **3 is returned as float64**.

My question is: how to parse a json string with the "minimum type" so that `3` will return `int32` and not the maximum type `3` => `float64`?

Assumption: my Json is huge and only have primitive types and I want a minimum value that is really float64 to continue to show `float64`.

Clarification:
A "minimum type" means that if `3` can be considered both `int32` and `float64` the "minimum type" will be `int32`, which is the exact type you'll get when running this:
`reflect.TypeOf(3).string()`

Comment: Define a struct. If you parse to interface{} you literally say "I don't care about the type".

Comment: Your terminology of "minimum type" and "maximum type" is confusing. Types aren't comparable... I really have no idea what that means.

Comment: JSON is based on JavaScript, and in JavaScript all numbers are float64, so  unless you specify a type, numbers will be decoded into float64.

Comment: I understand what are saying, so let's start with something simpler. I want to `Json.Unmarshel()` each value float64 type to int without specifying specific key names. Is that even possible. Check out @maerics answer and my comment on it, he's getting closer to what I'm trying to do. Obviously I can write a method to do it for me after the `Unmarsheling`, I'm looking for a way to avoid additional conversion methods. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot describe your data in a struct then your options are to:

1. Use a [`json.Decoder`](https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go#TOC_7.) to convert the values to your desired types as they are parsed.
2. Parse the document into a generic interface and post-process the value types.

Option #1 is the most flexible and can likely be implemented to be more performant than the other option since parsing and transformation could be performed in a single pass of the data.

Option #2 might be simpler but will require two passes over the data. Here is an example of what the post-processing step might look like:

```
func TransformValueTypes(o map[string]interface{}) {
  for k, v := range o {
    // Convert nil values to *string type.
    if v == interface{}(nil) {
      o[k] = (*string)(nil)
    }
    // Convert numbers to int32 if possible
    if x, isnumber := v.(float64); isnumber {
      if math.Floor(x) == x {
        if x >= math.MinInt32 && x <= math.MaxInt32 {
          o[k] = int32(x)
        }
        // Possibly check for other integer sizes here?
      }
      // Possibly check if float32 is possible here?
    }
    // Check for maps and slices here...
  }
}
```

So if you call `TransformValueTypes(data)` then your types will look like:

```
// my_int     -> 3     (int32)
// my_string  -> <nil> (*string)
// my_string2 -> "foo" (string)
// my_float   -> 1.23  (float64)
```

Of course, your transform function could also apply type transformation logic based on the key name.

Importantly, note that if your document might have additional structure not mentioned in your question (such as nested objects or arrays) then your transform function will need to account for them by more value type checking, recursive calls, and iteration.

Comment: This is a good answer and it's very similar to my own implementation - I'm using struct and switch cases that does this check for me. A great solution would be to show how to do this with a  Json decoder with a single pass, but without declaring the map keys - that's something I didn't manage to do. Thanks for the effort, well deserved an upvote.
BTW, I added a clarification to my question based on your feedback..

Answer (score 4):

Since you are unmarshaling into a map of `interface{}`, the following section of the [golang `json.Unmarshal` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) pertains:

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:
>   ...
>   float64, for JSON numbers
>   string, for JSON strings
>   ...

As such, to unmarshal your sample data into your desired types you should define a struct type which contains the desired field/type mappings, for example:

```
type MyType struct {
    MyInt    int     `json:"my_int"`
    MyString *string `json:"my_string"`
}

foo := MyType{}
jsonstr := `{"my_int": 3, "my_string": null}`

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstr), &foo)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
// foo => main.MyType{MyInt:3, MyString:(*string)(nil)}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in the assumptions my Json file is huge and dynamic. I can't specify 100 keys that will change by name every few weeks. I'm trying to figure out how to write something similar to your answer, without specifying a specific key like `my_int` and `my_string`. Any idea? - is there a way to specify this Json struct conversion by value types and not by key name?